# How do I turn off this two-pipe steam radiator?

Tags: valve, radiator, steam, shutoff

We live in an NYC apartment with steam heat. The noise of this radiator is driving us crazy because it's in the bedroom. We want to turn it off. The solution seems to be to shut the intake, the same way you would if you wanted to separate this unit from the system to service it. However, this set-up doesn't look quite like any of the instructions on turning off radiators that I've found online.

My question is: How do I close the intake on this radiator?

### What I tried

I tried turning the screw on the right hand side clockwise, and it appeared to tighten, but did not shut off the intake. I tried taking a pair of pliers and turning the nut underneath the screw clockwise (very stiff), but I stopped when it seemed to start leaking steam around the top of the nut (and turned it counter clockwise a turn or so to undo).

### Photos

Here's the whole radiator. I'm assuming intake is on the right & outflow on the left.
[image: Image of entire radiator]

Close-up of the intake: there's a screw on top, then a long narrow bit, and then the nut I tried to tighten.
[image: Intake]

Close-up of the outflow: there's also a nut over here (on the right), but I figure this is the output, so I'd just be trapping steam/water in the radiator if I managed to shut this.
[image: Outflow]

Answer (score 3):

The item on the left is the steam trap and can not be regulated or shut off. stay away from this item. The shut-off valve is the item with the screw on the top. Turn the nut ccw (counter clockwise), just slightly about a 1/4 turn, then put a wrench on the stem above the nut, I would use a 6" or 8" pipe wrench or vise grips, and try to turn cw (clockwise) until it stops. This be the closed position. Do not put too much torque on this  stem. If you can't turn it, have someone that works on steam valves turn it. You do not want to break it or twist it off. After shutting the valve "off" turn the nut cw to tighten, not too tight.  You could also turn it part way to control the heat output if needed. If you still can not get this valve to close and want to control the heat output try covering the top with a board, cardboard, or wrap part or all of it with aluminum cooking foil. This is a steam system and the noise could be coming from above or beneath your apartment. Noise will travel in the pipes.   HOPE THIS HELPS